# Remove space on the left and right

Tags: graphics

I use `includegraphics` to show an image in a LaTeX document. I want to show this picture as big as possible therefore I want LaTeX to ignore space on the left and right on that one page where I want to display an image so image would appear in the whole page without any white space. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use `\resizebox` maybe or simple indicate the width and the length of the page you are working on.

Comment: Package `pdfpages` might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify an over-width image and then just use negative space to pull it in to the margin

```
\begin{center}
\hspace*{-1cm}%
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm\relax]{...}%
\hspace*{-1cm}%
\end{center}
```

will make the image overlap the margins 1cm on either side. Adjust the lengths to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, it works great! Just one question, can I be sure that it will work the same way for every person as it works on my pdf reader?

Comment: @hey not sure what part you are concerned about, it is as likely to work as typesetting `hello world` anything can go wrong but there is no reason to think that that is less likely to work than any other part of the document.

Answer (score 3):

Try using TikZ to place the figure and `width=\paperwidth` for the size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] at (current page.center) 
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]